# What is the name of this Visual Studio UI element and how do I customise it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

This is found at the bottom of editor windows in Visual Studio:

[image]

What is it called?  The editor status bar?

I can't seem to find Visual Studio Extensibility docs on how it can be customised. Can it be customised and if so can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-status-bar?view=vs-2022

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks but IIUC that's not the status bar. I think the status bar is at the bottom of VS?

Comment: Oh...i think this is the "designer region" of the status bar.... hmm